# I want to calculate monthly mean precipitation and a chart in GEE but I get "Error generating chart: User memory limit exceeded."

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am analyzing impact of wildfire on precipitation patterns and I'd like to see the monthly mean precipitation over a region (point) to see if it is decreasing or increasing. I am still dealing why I get "Error generating chart: User memory limit exceeded" since my codes seems to be clear.
If anyone can help me I will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!!

Here I share my codes:

```
// portugal shapefile
var port_shp = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-geoyons/assets/portugal");

// burned area
var burnt_area_p = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-geoyons/assets/burnt_area_s_p")
                     .select('area_ha')

var clipImg = function(image){
  return image.clip(port_shp);
}

// **************** 01. Monthly Precipitation *********************

var collPP = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06")
                  .map(clipImg);
                  
var pp = collPP.select('precipitationCal');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2014, 2023);

var monthPP_sum = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function(y) {
        return months.map(function (m) {
        return pp.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                .sum()
                .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1));
  });

}).flatten());
//print(monthPP_sum)

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series(monthPP_sum.select('precipitationCal'), point, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000);
//print(chart);


// ******************** 02. Annual Precipitation **********************

var collPP = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06")
                  .map(clipImg);
                  
var pp = collPP.select('precipitationCal');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2002, 2023);

var yearPP_sum = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    years.map(function(y) {
      return pp.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                .sum().set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, 1, 1))
    }).flatten());
  

var chart_pp_annual = ui.Chart.image.series(yearPP_sum.select('precipitationCal'), point, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000);
print(chart_pp_annual);


// **************** 03. Monthly mean Precipitation *********************

var years = ee.List.sequence(2014, 2023);

var monthPP_mean = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    years.map(function(y) {
      return monthPP_sum.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                .mean().set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, 1, 1))
    }).flatten());

var chart_pp_month_mean = ui.Chart.image.series(monthPP_mean.select('precipitationCal'), point, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000);
print(chart_pp_month_mean);
```

Here is the link to GEE: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a0be0393623f5809fcb272ba87513e1d

I am expecting to see the chart of monthly mean precipitation.